# calling gRPC server doesn't return expected data in Node

Tags: node.js, grpc

I'm trying to create a simple Notes CRUD API using [this](https://medium.com/@alfianlosari/building-grpc-service-server-note-crud-api-with-node-js-bcc5478d5bdb) tutorial. The tutorial claims that calling the `List` method in server( `node get_notes.js`), from client should return `notes` array, but I am always getting an empty object.

**server.js**

```
const grpc = require('grpc')
const protoLoader = require('@grpc/proto-loader')
const packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync('notes.proto');
const notesProto = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition);

const notes = [
    { id: '1', title: 'Note 1', content: 'Content 1'},
    { id: '2', title: 'Note 2', content: 'Content 2'}
]

const server = new grpc.Server()

server.addService(notesProto.NoteService.service, {
    list: (_, callback) => {
        callback(null, notes)
    },
})

server.bind('127.0.0.1:50051', grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure())
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:50051')
server.start()
```

**client.js**

```
const grpc = require('grpc')
const protoLoader = require('@grpc/proto-loader')

const packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync('notes.proto');
const notesProto = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition);

const NoteService = notesProto.NoteService

const client = new NoteService('localhost:50051',
    grpc.credentials.createInsecure())
module.exports = client
```

**get_notes.js**

```
const client = require('./client')
client.list({}, (error, notes) => {
    if (!error) {
        console.log('successfully fetch List notes')
        console.log(notes)
    } else {
        console.error(error)
    }
})
```

**notes.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";

service NoteService {
    rpc List (Empty) returns (NoteList) {}
}
message Empty {}

message Note {
    string id = 1;
    string title = 2;
    string content = 3;
}

message NoteList {
   repeated Note notes = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `NoteList` message type contains a single field `notes` that is a list of `Note` messages. To send a message of that type you need to send an object with a single field that is a list of `Note`-like objects. In this case, that should look like this:

```js
const notes = { notes: [
    { id: '1', title: 'Note 1', content: 'Content 1'},
    { id: '2', title: 'Note 2', content: 'Content 2'}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked, but is there a way to send that original object? How should I refine the message format in `.proto` file to send the original object?

Comment: This is the best way to send an array of objects. One possible alternative would be to use a response stream, and send each element of the array as a separate response message. That would mainly be useful if not all of the response data is available immediately.